# Footnote for a mathematical variable with exponent

Tags: footnotes

I was wondering what is a good practice for creating a footnote just next to a mathematical variable with an exponent, without confusing the footnote number with the variable exponent. Here is an example for illustration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    $x^2$\footnote{This is a footnote for describing a notation detail, for example. The footnote number is not to be confused with the exponent of the variable x.} is the square root of $x$.
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any idea you could provide.

Comment: I believe the best way is to rephrase the sentence such that this doesn't happen...

Comment: "I was wondering what is a good practice..." The only conceivable "good practice" is to place the footnote marker somewhere else...

Comment: As other say, it is probably best to avoid the footnote symbol there. In Lansburghs typesetting guide, he suggests to use parentheses around raised footnotenumbers in mathematical text. That would be something like `x^2(¹)'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not a good idea, but these help.  Using symbols shows that they are not exponents.  OTOH, there are only so many symbols available, hense the minipage.  Hyperref adds colored boxes around the footnotemarks.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\fnspecial=\@fnsymbol
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\def\thempfn{\fnspecial{\value{mpfootnote}}}%
$x^2$ \footnote{This is a quadratic.}\quad
$x^3$ \footnote{This is a cubic.}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

---

This creates `\footlink` to link the text directly to a footnote without adding a footnote mark.  The footnotes are numbered normally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\footlink}[2]{% #1=linked text, #2=footnote text
  \refstepcounter{footnote}% or \@mpfn
  \hyperlink{Hfootnote.\arabic{footnote}}{#1}%
  \footnotetext[\value{footnote}]{\raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{%
      \hypertarget{Hfootnote.\arabic{footnote}}{\null}}%
    #2}}

\begin{document}

\footlink{$x^2$}{This is a quadratic.}\quad
\footlink{$x^3$}{This is a cubic.}

\end{document}
```